# Cannot install gems to use in homemade filters logstash 1.5.2

Tags: rubygems, installation, logstash

I need to install gems in logstash 1.5.2

I have made a filter that need the `typhoeus` ruby gem.
I have tried to install it with `gem install typhoeus` and by setting the environment variable **GEM_HOME** to `pathToLogstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911246/how-to-change-the-path-where-ruby-gems-are-installed-on-os-10-6-6-ruby-1-8-and-r%20%20%20here)).
A folder `typhoeus` can now be found in `pathToLogstash-1.5.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems`.

Yet, when I launch logstash with my filter named "indexFilter", for instance :

```
#test.conf
input {file {  path => "/tmp/test.log" } }

filter { indexFilter { } }

output {stdout {}}
```

launching

```
bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

will results in

```
The error reported is:
  Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'indexFilter'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the indexFilter filter plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- typhoeus
```

I have found ways to install gems with previous versions of logstash (<=1.4) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984620/how-to-add-gems-into-logstash%20here)

Can anyone give me the way to do the same in logstash 1.5 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install the `typhoeus` gem manually. The new logstash plugin environment takes care of your dependencies. You just have to mention them in your code (twice).

### Dependency prep

For a new filter plugin you should have a directory structure like this:

```
├── Gemfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── lib
│   └── logstash
│       └── filters
│           └── mypluginname.rb
├── logstash-filter-mypluginname.gemspec
└── spec
    └── filters
        └── mypluginname_spec.rb
```

At the top of the `lib/logstash/filters/mypluginname.rb`:

```
require "typhoeus"
```

And at the end of your `logstash-filter-mypluginname.gemspec`:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency "typhoeus", '>= 0.7.3'
```

### Build & Install

When you have all those things done you can auto-load your dependencies and build the gem (make sure that your directory is initialized as a git repository):

```
bundle install
rake vendor
bundle exec rspec
gem build logstash-filter-mypluginname.gemspec
```

Afterwards install your plugin using logstash's built-in plugin manager:

```
LS_HOME/bin/plugin install logstash-filter-mypluginname-0.0.1.gem
```

Verify the installation:

```
LS_HOME/bin/plugin list
```

### Final remarks

I would really recommend you to stick to logstash's [How to write a filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html) guide. I've done it a few times and in my opinion this is the best way. I've experienced some issues with bundle and jruby versions so I would recommend you to use [RVM](http://rvm.io/) to get things done.

Comment: I was stuck in a similar problem for hours and your post help me to resolve it, thanks !